# How to replace single line in the text file with bash?

Tags: bash, sed

I would like to replace one (first line) in `app.yaml` file I have with bash. 
The file looks like below:

```
application: my-appid
version: 1
...
```

`my-appid` there should be replaced with `my-appid2`.

I tried to use

```
sed -i.bak -e "s/application: \.*/application: \ 2/" app.yaml
```

but in result I get `application:  2my-appid`.

How should I fix it? (my-appid shouldn't be hardcoded)

Comment: Why are you escaping the `.`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed -i.bak -e 's/application: .*/&2/' app.yaml
```

`&` in the replacement gets replaced with everything that matched the regexp.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i.bak -e '1s/ .*/ my-appid2/' app.yaml
```

On line 1, replace a space followed by anything, with a space followed by your new app name.